# Plot scatterplot without y-values in plotly.js

Tags: scatter-plot, plotly.js

I would like to implement a scatterplot over timeline using plotly.js, similar to the image below.
[image]

Plotly takes in x and y values to plot the chart. But I will be plotting x-values(time) without any y-values. Is it possible to do so ? Or can I generate random values for y-axis ? Any suggestion or idea would be great.

Comment: I realise I am stating the obvious but by mathematical definition x and y would provide a precise location on the graph, assuming no y value is given it could assume zero but everything would be at the bottom(which i dont think you want?)

with this in mind...

perhaps then you want to parse the y-value in as an ordering element? 

y = 1 --> I want this item to appear at the bottom

y = 50 --> This element to appear further up

etc

etc